# Swift if statement in modifier

Tags: xcode, swiftui

So I have an basic Taskview:

```swift
TabView {
    NavigationView {
        TasksView()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "bookmark")
        Text("Tasks")
    }
    
    NavigationView {
        ShopView()
    }
    .tabItem {
        Image(systemName: "cart.fill")
        Text("Shop")
    }
}
.environment(\.colorScheme, isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
```

And now I want to add an if statement to .environment. So like if Default: .environment(.colorScheme, isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You are currently using the ternary operator, which acts like an `if` statement, returning the left operand if `true` and the right operand if `false`.

Comment: I want to add an second if Statement that runs the whole thing (.environment(\.colorScheme, isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)) only if CustomSheme is true

Comment: @Bwlok, then edit your question to overtly say so.  Indeed, please try to write that code yourself in your question as a proposed answer, but then show where your proposal fails or causes something perplexing. You can take your question from sort-of okay to good/great by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Environment` to call the current color scheme. Then you can create a color variable.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) private var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            NavigationView {
                TasksView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "bookmark")
                Text("Tasks")
            }
            .foregroundColor(titleColor) // <- here
            NavigationView {
                ShopView()
            }
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "cart.fill")
                Text("Shop")
            }
            .foregroundColor(titleColor) // <- here
        }
    }
    
    private var titleColor: Color {
        switch colorScheme {
        case .light:
            return .red
        case .dark:
            return .yellow
        @unknown default:
            return .blue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution. Use an ObservableObject class, store and save the variable. Set it as a `StateObject` and set as `environmentObject` in your `App`, then you can handle updates in your `View` by accessing the variable.

```swift
class ColorScheme: ObservableObject {
    @AppStorage("dark") var dark = false
}

 
struct MyApp: App {
    @StateObject var colorscheme = ColorScheme()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(colorscheme)
                .colorScheme(colorscheme.dark ? .dark : .light)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var colorscheme: ColorScheme
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle("Color Scheme", isOn: colorscheme.$dark)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: dark]
[image: light]